# Very old Ricoh camera and lenses to work with newer Canon EOS camera

Tags: lens, dslr, old-lenses

I've been given an old bag of Ricoh camera and lenses and I find that it would be such a waste not to be able to use in some way all this again for something.

Can you give me some suggestions as to how to use this kind of equipment with a newer camera like a Canon 600D?

EDIT: The lenses in question:

1. Ricoh (Rikenon) 1:2 50mm.
2. Vivatar 80-200mm macro lens.
3. A whole bunch of Zivnon 52mm close up lenses. (Probably just get an adapter ring for these)

Just took some pics of the [50mm which you can find here](https://plus.google.com/photos/114076004803502251346/albums/5967936744660365953?authkey=CJikn-v0vO_YPQ)

And the [Vivatar 80-200mm here](https://plus.google.com/photos/114076004803502251346/albums/5967952998678094737?authkey=CMWnsYWWgsTlHw)

Comment: Can you list what you have specifically? Some of it may work with modern Pentax — possibly with slight modification to the lenses as they may have an extra pin which can get stuck.

Comment: Yeah, list of model/s would be good.

Comment: Added the lenses as requested with links to images. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Ricoh, historically, used the Pentax K-mount for their film SLR cameras, but with a slight and important modification: they added a pin that's used to indicate the aperture is in auto mode for shutter priority use. With some careful work, you can [remove the pin](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/post/25959708) for use on K-mount bodies made by Pentax or Samsung or with a [K to EF adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Y3EJMU) for Canon EOS digital and film variants. Nevertheless, if you have Ricoh K-mount lenses (with the P setting), then that pin ***has to go***.

You can confirm if you have these based on this helpful bit of info from Wikipedia: *The R-K mount is used on Rikenon P lenses, Ricoh bodies that include the letter 'P' in their model number, and some non-Ricoh lenses.*

Now, it's also possible that the Ricoh lenses are M42 screw-mount lenses also known, funny enough, as the Pentax mount when most film cameras had it and Pentax was the SLR king. If that is the case, and it's easy to tell by just looking for threads on the lens mount, then you can easily get adapters for it for a variety of cameras including your [Canon option](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001G4P9YG).

On the ironic side, Pentax is now owned by Ricoh...

Comment: Many thanks Joanne. I'm reading a fair amount to understand what I'm getting myself into. I've compared pictures and it seems it is K mount when I look at this instructable. http://m.instructables.com/id/How-to-modify-K-Mount-lenses-to-fit-a-full-frame-C/?ALLSTEPS.

Comment: Edited to include the P setting will have the pin.

Answer (score 2):

I had a couple of Ricoh lenses and tried to use them on my Nikon. I tried an adapter which promised to allow focusing K mount lenses on it by using a lens to compensate the longer flange distance.. and it failed miserably. In practice the images were foggy and unsharp unless the lens was stepped down to at least f/4 if not f/5.6 - which totally defeats the purpose of using old lenses: if you have to step down that much, just go with the cheapest kit zooms and you get metering, autofocus and stabilization.

Now, technically Canon EF flange distance is lower than Pentax-K ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance)) but I doubt any adapter could be just like 1.5mm thick, so the same considerations apply unless you find a very thin adapter.

Another way to use them exists, however, specially for the 50mm 1:2 : using a reversal ring for macro photos. For example [this photo](http://www.flickr.com/photos/marcomp/8027612482/) Was taken with a reversed Ricoh 50mm f1.7 non-P.

Comment: Thanks Marco. If all else fails I wouldn't mind using them as macro lenses.

Comment: Adapters that add glass alter the performance of the lens.

Comment: JoanneC: yes, that was my point, along with "with so similar flange distances you probably have no other choice".